# Cordova issue moving image to persistent storage and displaying it

Tags: cordova, camera, local-storage, persistent-storage

I've got an issue with my code and i would really appreciate any help that you guys can provide as I'm quite new to cordova.

Here's the issue, I take an image which is then re-named and placed in a new directory which I have created. The image is then pushed out to a sqlite database and read back to the html using a .

The code runs perfectly and doesn't return any errors but my images doesn't display? It may have something to do with the path but I can't resolve the issue?

Here's a link to a pluker of the code: 
`[http://plnkr.co/edit/964V9VSFMpf6a9kYeNKW?p=preview][1]`

Any tips would be greatly appreciated:)

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Can anyone help or point me in the right direction please?